# Displaying array results of query in another file

Tags: php, mysql

I am refreshing my memory on OOP and learning how to apply it to PHP with a focus on separation of concerns (MVC).  For practice, I found and edited some code online.  The function *query()* returns data from my MySQL database.  Here is that class file:

```
 <?php
    // ClassPractice.php

    class ClassPractice {
        public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $name) {
            $this->host = $host;
            $this->user = $user;
            $this->pass = $pass;
            $this->name = $name;
        }

        protected function connect() {
            return new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->name);
        }

        public function query($query) {
            $db = $this->connect();
            $result = $db->prepare($query);
            $result->execute();
            $result->bind_result($username);

            while ( $row = $result->fetch_object() ) {
                $rows[] = $row;
            }

            return $rows;
        }
    }
 ?>
```

There was no example of how this class was instantiated in another file, so I did that myself and called the *query()* method from this file:

```
    <?php
       // index.php

       include('ClassPractice.php');

       $class = new ClassPractice('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');

       $results = $class->query("SELECT username FROM user");

       // Display formatted results of query here

?>
```

Since the rules of MVC dictate that the view must be handled separately from the model and controller, I would like to display the results of the *query()* method with this file.  I've researched this endlessly, but haven't found anything specific to what I'm trying to do.  Normally, I would assign the method call to a variable and then manipulate or display the variable as needed.  This does not appear to be an option in this case.  I tried assigning the query in the method call to an array variable and also using a foreach method to display the results.  So far nothing has worked.

Comment: EDIT: Assigned call to query() method to variable $results in index.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is wrong, change 'the while' for this line

```
while ( $result->fetch() ) {
$rows[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: I had tried that, too, but I guess my foreach was incorrect.  I changed my while loop and fixed my foreach loop and it works now.  Thanks!